# How to have 2 alerts pop up in the same k bar

Tags: alert, pine-script

if                                                                              L_basic_condt

strategy.entry                                                              ("L", strategy.long , alert_message=l_buy )

if                                                                              S_basic_condt

strategy.entry                                                              ("S", strategy.short, alert_message=s_buy)

strategy.close("L", when = S_basic_condt, alert_message=l_sell)

strategy.close("S", when = L_basic_condt, alert_message=s_sell)

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

When the long condition is met, i enter the market with the alert "l_buy" pop up
However, when is short condition is met, only the alert "s_buy" pop up without the "l_sell" alert.
I want to make it a autotrading strategy with these alerts.
How to pop up the alert "s_buy" and "l_sell" at the same time.

P.S. I have already separated the long condition and short condition for alert making.

Comment: Please edit your question to represent the code as `code` and use Stackoverflow guidelines. You just simply pasted here a text with tons of spaces. Also, without indentation nobody will know if the last 2 line is in the IF block or not (probably is, but it is best for you to state what you want instead of someone else figuring it out).